# Unable to Enable Vim Conceal

Tags: vimrc, plugin-vim-latex

I'm running ArchLinux using the xfce4 terminal with vim-latex. Using this setup, I tried to follow the instructions [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150926153104/https://b4winckler.wordpress.com/2010/08/07/using-the-conceal-vim-feature-with-latex/) to conceal latex commands with unicode. However, after much effort, I still cannot get any concealing.

I followed all the directions from above, namely put

```
set cole=2
let g:tex_conceal="adgm"
```

in my `~/.vimrc` file.

However, there is no difference even when I try type `:set cole=2` manually in vim.

At first, I thought it might be because xfce4-terminal is having trouble with utf-8, but I then tried to edit .tex files in rxvt-unicode which definitely supports utf-8. Still, there wasn't any change. I also checked that indeed my vim is compiled with the `+conceal` option.

Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Very belatedly, this seems to work okay for me in Vim 8.1 for LaTeX content such as `\( \Phi \)`. What version of Vim are you using? Is syntax highlighting switched on and the filetype set? Could you add a very small sample LaTeX file where it doesn't work for you?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I think I figured it out eventually, although I don't remember what I did four years ago :(

Comment: Sorry I didn't see it sooner. Glad you got it working, though! I'm going to vote to close this question, as I don't think there's enough details in it to figure out why you couldn't get it working originally.